# debian bookworm - plugging in ethernet shuts off display

Tags: debian, ethernet, display

I recently migrated my ASUS thinpc (Ryzen 3 4300U) from bullseye to bookworm. I use a KVM switch (KCEVE 4 Ports KVM Switch) to share my external monitor, mouse and keyboard between this PC and my work laptop (DELL/Intel).

I typically use ethernet for internet rather than WiFi as i get more consistent speeds on ethernet.

I have a strange issue with the ethernet connection ever since i upgraded to debain bookworm.  when i jack in the ethernet, my display switches off. it comes back as soon as i unplug and what is strange is that, when my ethernet is jacked in, the external monitor doesn't work even with my laptop (when i toggle the KVM switch).  I can understand there being some driver issues within the Linux scope but i really don't understand what's causing it to spill over to the KVM switch and monitor for all devices connected.  btw, i am currently using 3 of 4 KVM ports, the 3rd is a Chromebit.

Any ideas on what could be happening please?  I have too much interference on my wifi channels and would really love to be on ethernet as far as possible.  I have been aggressively updating bookworm in the hope that it is one of those early issues that might get fixed in an update but no luck so far.

Comment: Did you check the logs to see what the system may be doing

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: That seems more like a hardware issue to me. Possibly a power supply problem or a grounding/earthing issue. Are you using a STP/FTP (i.e. shielded) ethernet cable? If so, try an UTP (unshielded) cable instead to avoid ground loops between devices.

Comment: It could be a electrical issue.  I have noticed one other issue with my monitor. it goes off and on when certain light switches are togged in the room.  It is not predictable but not very rare.  To your question, i am using a Cat6e cable.  It says UTP FR-PVC on the cable

Answer (score 1):

A few steps to help you get more info:

- Check `dmesg` and `journalctl` for anything logged when you plug/unplug it
- See how it behaves when you don't use the KVM switch and instead plug in the peripherals directly
- See how it behaves when there's only the one computer plugged in

I'm leery of how it's doing USB3 power delivery from multiple sources, though that may be unwarranted.

Comment: I will try this. thanks!